# Excel vba does not recognize Sheets("Order").Select

Tags: excel, vba

I have had code working for years using Office 365. Recently purchased a company out of state and are setting up 2 computers for them to use with our system. On just 1 of the computers, I get a "application-defined or object-defined error" when the below code is ran, Sheets("ORDER").Select.

```
    Case "Order View"
        GoBack = ActiveSheet.Name
        Sheets("hist").Cells(Sheets("hist").Cells(1000, 3).End(xlUp).row + 1, 3) = ActiveSheet.Name
        **Sheets("ORDER").Select**
```

I have other Case conditions that select different sheets and they work fine. So I change the line to reference the index number of the sheet and it still fails!

```
        **Sheets(18).Select**
```

I put in different sheet Index numbers and they work fine, but I can't get my Order sheet to work.

Anytime I try to reference that 1 sheets' properties, my code crashes, but it's only on 1 computer out of probably 50! Even **ActiveSheet.Name** crashes when I am on the Orders sheet, but no other sheets.

Next, we uninstalled Office and reinstalled it and that did not fix it either.

Help!

Comment: You don't normally need to `Select` though. Maybe this is a good time to implement the points from [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Probably a good first step would be to qualify all your worksheet references with a workbook object.

Comment: On the computer which is having problems, try checking Tools > References in the VBA editor to make sure that none of the references are marked as "MISSING:"

Comment: @BigBen My workbook has 69 sheets in it and I use the `Select` to navigate around to the different sheets.

Comment: But you shouldn't do that.